# writeBytes puttin a CR

Tags: java, sockets

My java microservice write in a socket :

```java
serverOutput.writeBytes(gson.toJson(productFound).toString());
System.out.println(gson.toJson(productFound).toString());
```

The println displays the correct thing, which is what I expected :

```
{
  "id": "S10_1678",
  "name": "1969 Harley Davidson Ultimate Chopper",
  "price": "48.81"
}
```

But when I receive it in my Node server and that I print it before sending it to the browser,

```js
client.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
  res.end(data.toString());
});
```

it seems that a CR has be injected, which makes the JSON format no longer correct. The console.log prints me :

```
{

  "id": "S10_16
78",
  "name": "1969 Harley Davidson Ultimate Chopper",
  "price": "48.81"
}
```

So the browser only receive `{` and tells me that the Json format is not correct.

Comment: Have you tried sniffing the network traffic to verify whether a CR is actually present in the raw bytes being transmitted by `writeBytes()`? Rather than using `writeBytes()`, try encoding the `String` to a `byte[]` array using `String.getBytes()` and then send the `byte[]` using `write()` instead. That will help you remove any doubt about whether a CR is getting injected or not. Might just be a bug on the receiving end.

Comment: Thank you ! I did that and it worked. I still cannot understand, why did using write with getting the bytes from the string work ? Why did writeByte add a carriage return ?

Comment: Did you *verify* with a network sniffer, like Wireshark or Fiddler, that `writeBytes()` was the one actually injected the CR? `writeBytes()` simply truncates off the top 8 bits of each `char` in the `String` and transmits the bottom 8 bits as-is. CR is byte `0x0D`, is it possible that your `String` has a `char` that looks like `0x##0D`?